# Create a WebLogic development domain with custom memory

Tags: java, weblogic

I've been trying to automate the creation of our development environment by combining batch files and WLST, but I am struggling to change the memory WebLogic server will start with.

Currently we are manually changing the memory settings in the `<DOMAIN_HOME>/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd` script, but this is a workaround. It should be possible to to do it automatically without much effort.

### Setting the Domain

The script that sets the Domain in pretty simple:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
set MW_HOME=C:\dev\wls1036_dev
set DOMAIN_HOME=C:\dev\domain
cd %MW_HOME%
call configure.cmd
mkdir %DOMAIN_HOME%
cd %DOMAIN_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.management.username=weblogic -Dweblogic.management.password=welcome1 weblogic.Server
```

I've tried to use some variables in this script such as `MEM_ARGS`, `JAVA_OPTIONS`, but none of these are forwarded to the final configuration of the domain, later it always starts with 512 heap, and 128 perm, which are not enough.

### WLST memory start args

We are using Eclipse, and it does call the `startWebLogic.cmd` as start script. It is the standard configuration.

I tried to use the following WLST script. It does set the server start arguments, but WebLogic is not using those properties and loads not enough memory.

```
edit()
startEdit()
cd('/Servers/myserver/ServerStart/myserver')
cmo.setArguments('-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m')
activate()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We are using WebLogic 10.3.6 development ZIP distribution.

Comment: Find the environment variable that WLS uses to set Java arguments, and set that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way of setting values when executing WebLogic from Eclipse. It'll call the batch script and, at least at current version, does not allow to send dynamic parameters.

We solved it making the `setDomainEnv.cmd` file part of our versioned configuration:

1. Copy the `setDomainEnv.cmd` file to your version control configuration.
2. Edit whatever you want (memory, etc)
3. Copy the file like `copy custom\setDomainEnv.cmd %DOMAIN_HOME%\bin /y` when running your development environment configuration script.

Now every time you configure your development environment memory values will be ready without manual intervention.

You have to reedit your stuff when updating WebLogic, so you don't end up with an outdated component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trick for getting *ServerStart arguments*:

1. Write simple offline WLST-script to get arguments from `config.xml`:

*getArguments.py*

```
import sys

readDomain(sys.argv[1])
cd('Server/%s/ServerStart/NO_NAME_0' % sys.argv[2])
argsFile = open('arguments.txt', 'w')
print >>argsFile, cmo.arguments
```

2. Add this script to `startWeblogic.cmd` like:

*startWebLogic.cmd*

```
...

set DOMAIN_HOME=%~dp0

path\to\wlst.cmd getArguments.py %DOMAIN_HOME% admin_server_name
set /p EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES=<arguments.txt

call "%DOMAIN_HOME%\bin\startWebLogic.cmd" %*
```